# running shell command login into node

Tags: shell

When I run this command after I login to the server I get the correct output:

```
$ sudo echo "show stat" | sudo -u haproxy nc -U /var/run/haproxy.sock | grep awsmdjjkdd | awk -F ',' '{print $16}'
UP
```

But when I try doing it from script I get a different output:

```
$ ssh lakrah@1298.9879.24 "sudo echo "show stat" | sudo -u haproxy nc -U /var/run/haproxy.sock | grep awsmdjjkdd | awk -F ',' '{print $16}'" 
:8
```

Why?

Comment: My guess is that this is a quoting issue: Drop the `awk` to see the full output/error.

Comment: tried droping awk it is throwing me an error saying - F command not found

Comment: ... Ehm ... It sounds like you only removed `awk` and not the arguments ... ?

Comment: thanks Carpetsmoker ..figured it out awak is talking $18 as a variable and printing out 8 placing /$18 should work

Comment: I think you mean `\$` ;-)